# php linking of webpages which contains two or more links

Tags: php, session, indexing, edit

.In one of my webpages i.e to edit a table in PHP  I have link like this:

```
<a href=index.php?getpage=edit.php?id=$row['id']></a>
```

How can i get INTO My index page since it has two links it has to redirect to index page and it will redirect to edit page using id variable to identify please help me out answer will be highly apprecited

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking for.. please describe more carefully your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will not work

```
index.php?getpage=edit.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>
```

You can specify something like this:

```
index.php?getpage=edit.php&id=<?= $row['id'] ?>
```

by checking the value of the request variable 'getpage', you can redirect it to the edit page and the parameter 'id' will already tell you which ID needs to be edited.